# How to include this piece of text in a table?

Tags: tables

I have optimal parameters for the models I tested, however, the parameter values are the same for each model. Therefore I don't want a column for each parameter value, as that would be needless repetition. However, I am not sure where to put the optimal parameter values in the table (and how to do so so it looks pleasant) - I obviously want to ensure that it is clear it applies to all the models in the table. This is the text I'd like to include:

`(Optimal Parameters: $c = 0.01, \gamma = 0.5, d =2$)`

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[allow-number-unit-breaks]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering 
\caption{Percentage of Correct Predictions and AUC Values by Kernel} 
\label{tab34} 
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llSS}
\toprule \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Kernel} & \textbf{\% Correct Classification} & \textbf{AUC Values}\\
\midrule
Model 20 & Linear & 49.9 & 0.50\\
Model 21 & Polynomial ($d = 2$) & 93.6 & 0.98 \\
Model 22 & Radial & 49.9 & 0.50 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: design isn't really on topic, if you decided how you want it to look, asking how to to it in tex would be on topic, meanwhile  you are missing a `@{}` at the end of your table preamble for a centred setting

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I know how I want it to look - possibly with the text above the column headers, but not part of the caption...but let me think about it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, caption}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage[allow-number-unit-breaks]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Percentage of Correct Predictions and AUC Values by Kernel}
\label{tab34}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llSS}
\toprule
\thead{Model} & \thead{Kernel} & {\thead{\% Correct\\ Classification}} & {\thead{AUC Values}}\\
\midrule
Model 20 & Linear & 49.9 & 0.50\\
Model 21 & Polynomial ($d = 2$) & 93.6 & 0.98 \\
Model 22 & Radial & 49.9 & 0.50 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{(Optimal Parameters: $c = 0.01,\, \gamma = 0.5,\, d =2$)}\medskip \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]